# Does twitter support oauth2 for "login with twitter"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, passport.js

I want to do login with twitter with [passport-twitter](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-twitter/).

The problem is passport-twitter uses session, and I have servers controlled by Load Balancer without session.

So this is a problem to do, because its not gonna work:

```
app.use(expressSession({ secret: 'secret', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.session());
```

Facebook for example dont need session to do login with facebook.

Did twitter support now oauth2 can I do login with twitter using oauth2 without session? in [twitter guide](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter) I can still see that they using oauth v1.

When the strategy need permissions it will redirect to: `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate`, I think the answer is token for oauth, not oauth2.

Comment: By looking at API docs, https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/token can be used to generate oath2 token and you can try to token to see if it works or not. I didn't try this though.

Comment: just edit my question. see last line. so what you say is for post and oauth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. At this time, Twitter does *not* support OAuth 2 for sign in with Twitter.

Comment: I have the same problem, can't access due to the session problem. @Andy please please support the oauth2 - thanks :)

Comment: Already on the roadmap [here](https://trello.com/c/qyyhk2JA/83-oauth-2-and-fine-grained-authorization-permissions-v2-twitter-api) for v2 of the API.

Comment: OAuth 2.0 user context is [currently in beta](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-context) for v2 of the Twitter API.